# Flutter setState changes state, but doesn't re-render

Tags: flutter

Suppose I have a widget, like so:

```
class ContactUsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ContactUsWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContactUsWidgetState createState() => _ContactUsWidgetState();
}

class _ContactUsWidgetState extends State<ContactUsWidget> {
   bool isLoading = false;

   @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Form(...)
   }
}
```

Inside of my Form, I have a Stack:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      color: isLoading ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
    ),...
  ]
);
```

and a button too:

```
FFButtonWidget(
    onPressed: () async {
       this.setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
          print(isLoading);
       });
                                               
       await sleep(Duration(seconds: 2));

       this.setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          print(isLoading);
       });
    },
)
```

However; when I press the button the value of `isLoading` changes (as I see from the prints), but the widget doesn't re-render, as the color of the container stays the same

Comment: *"but the widget doesn't re-render,"* - so the `build()` method is not called at all? tried to add some `print` there?

Comment: Yes, the build method is only called after both setState's have ran.

Comment: try using calling setState without 'this.'

Comment: `await sleep(Duration(seconds: 2));` -> `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));` - check "sleep" official docs, they say: *"Sleep for the duration specified in duration.

Use this with care, as no asynchronous operations can be processed in a isolate while it is blocked in a sleep call."*

Comment: my god @pskink , thank you for your informative response, I didn't realize the implications if sleep.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to `await sleep(Duration(seconds: 2));`, as detailed in @pskink's answer.